# Clear text area on radio button click and get text instead of value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here i am able to clear data but when i push value from other radio button its load again previous data which i don't want.

I want textarea data should be clear permanently on radio button click and should not load with any other.

Here is my code

```
    <div class="portlet-body">
@foreach($students as $student)
    <div>
        <input type="radio" value="{{$student->id}}" name="student_lists[]" onclick="getdata( {{ $student->id }} )"/>
        {{$lists->name}}
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div id="students-data"></div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

**script**

```
    <script>
function getdata(id)
{
    $('#textbx').val(null);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/students/'+id,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
        $('#students-data').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller method to get HTML**

```
public function loadData($id)
{
  $students = DB::table('students')->select('name' , 'id')->where('user_id' , $id)->get();
  $data = '';
    $data .= '<div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-1">
                      </label>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                          <label class="">';
                          foreach ($students as $student) {
                              $data .= "<input type='checkbox' class='chkbx' name='custom' onclick='push()' value='{$student->name}'/> {$student->name}
                                <span></span>";
                              }
                 $data .='</label>
                      </div>
                  </div>';
              return $data;
  }
```

**Script to push data in text area**

```
<script>
    function push()
    {
    $checks = $(".chkbx:checkbox");
    $checks.on('change', function() {
        var data = $checks.filter(":checked").map(function(i,v){
            return this.value;
        }).get().join("\n");

        $('#textbx').val(data);
    });
    }
</script>
```

Textarea where i push values

```
<textarea name="fields" id="textbx" class="form-control" rows="8" ></textarea>
```

Please help how can i hard reset textarea value.

Comment: i don't see any textarea in your code

Comment: sorry i update it now

Comment: how do you push values to that textarea?

Comment: i use onclick method above to push data in textbox

Comment: ok so from where do you want to reset the textarea?

Comment: when i push data mean clicks on radio button a div of checkboxes opens . then selected checkbox go in textarea as done in push script. I also write code to clear data on start of push script which clear once but when i push data of other radio button previous button data also come back which i don;t want..

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: @madalinivascu want to return text please update for it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the push function, keep the change event and delegate it so you can trigger the code on the dynamically added elements, select the checkboxes relative to your clicked checkobx

```
   $(function(){
        $('body').on('change',".chkbx:checkbox", function() {
            var data = $(this).parent().find(':checkbox:checked').map(function(i,v){
                return $(v).val();
            }).get().join("\n");

            $('#textbx').val(data);
        });
   });
```

if you have student->id as a value and want student->name to be apppended to the textarea then you need to alter your html as follows

add a custom attribute called data-name with the student name

```
 $data .= "<input type='checkbox' class='chkbx' name='custom' data-name=' {$student->name}' value='{$student->name}'/> {$student->name}
                                <span></span>";
```

and the js map to return:

```
return $(v).attr('data-id');
```

Comment: dear its working with value but i don't want push value i need to push text which will come from {$student->name}.... 
How to do for text instead of  return this.value;   .... 
Thanks please update answer

Comment: no dear this was not question it is... `$data .= "<input type='checkbox' class='chkbx' name='custom' value='{$student->id}'/> {$student->name}
                                <span></span>";` ..... In this code we returning student value mean id '{$student->id}' but i want name as above at end of code line '{$student->name}' ...

Comment: Might be something as return this.text;  but its not working

Comment: from what i can see in the question you have  `$data .= "<input type='checkbox' class='chkbx' name='custom' onclick='push()' value='{$student->name}'/> {$student->name}
                                <span></span>";` the value is `$student->name` not the student id

Comment: sir it will be student id '$student->id' to save ids in DB but i want display student name

Comment: Thank you so much Please one last help if you can ... 

I want to get also ids of data which i push in textarea {$student->id} how can i achieve please help to do this thanks

Comment: you do another map function for the ids man or use a each function and return both the id and the name, please accept the answer, if you have other question post a different stack overflow question

Answer (score 0):

At beginning before looping statement initialize your student-data variables to 0 or null.
All the variables you want to display should be initialized to 0 or NULL, so that every time function is called first the values will be set to null then **for** loop stores its values.